# defaultValue property in HTML not being set properly in my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

To summarize, the default value of my dropdown menu is not setting correctly. I'd like it to be "random_name_to_protect_privacy" but it's instead always set to 'fpc0' because that's the first element in the array that's passed into the dropdown menu. I tried using `defaultValue` but it doesn't appear to do anything.
So I have a main parent component that returns this:

```
return(
<div>
...
          <label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; Location: &nbsp;
            <MenuDropdown bots={props.botsList} onSelect={handlebotsChange} defaultValue={"re0"}/>
          </label> 
</div>
);
```

and my DropDown menu component looks like this:

```
const MenuDropdown = (props) => {
  let bots = props.bots

  const handleSelect = (event) => {
    const selectedbots = event.target.value;
    console.log("selected bots", selectedBot)
    props.onSelect(selectedBot)
  };

  return (
    <select onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e)} defaultValue={props.defaultValue}>
      {bots.map((bot) => (
        <option key={bot} value={bot}>
          {bot}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Quick screenshot of the default value:
[wrong default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOKhO.png)

and screenshot of all the values (what crossed out in red is what I'm trying to have show up as the default value):
[actual name not included for privacy reasons, but it's there, trust me :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxKhW.png)

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: maybe you are doing something more, it is working fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qtgllt?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: @SonuSindhu Thanks for that link! I've never heard of stackblitz before, but now that you shared it, I realized how amazing and helpful it is :)

Now onto the main issue. When I have a random list `const nodeList = ['testing', 're0'];` defined, it works. However, when I switch to `props.nodeList` where a GET request passes into props.nodeList after it finishes (the GET request takes a while-roughly 0.5 seconds-since my particular use case for the GETparses A TON of data), that's when the wrong default value is shown. So it's like a latency issue? Any follow-up thoughts?

Comment: maybe you can use if condition and only bind MenuDropdown once you got data until you can show loader?

Comment: @SonuSindhu That seems like a valid idea! Any idea on how that would look, code-wise (pseudo-code or whatever is fine). I'm new to React, so I want to make sure to do this correctly.

Comment: @SonuSindhu Any follow up?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the cause, but on line `<option key={bot} value={bots}>` maybe it should be `<option key={bot} value={bot}>` instead?

Comment: sorry, my code originally stated`value={bot}`, I just copied into the stack overflow post incorrectly @TaigeWang